# Select records after id after ordering by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's say we have a table ordered by weight

```
  select id, 
         weight
    from TABLE
order by weight
```

;

```
id     weight
---   -------
66     2.50
12    12.00
11    24.00
19    25.00
 6    44.00
 7    45.00
 8    47.00
 9    48.00
10    50.00
```

We want to return only records which are more or equal to weight of some id.
for example if we want id=7 then we will get

```
id     weight
---   -------
 7    45.00
 8    47.00
 9    48.00
10    50.00
```

or in another words, all records of the table ordered by weight from the row where id = 7.
We don't want weights, we want ids.

Comment: You mean weight is greater than from 45.00 as id 7 has this value right?

Comment: Yes, and we want "one select" sulution :)

Comment: Why do you want it to be single select? any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a simple inner query would do:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM   `TABLE`
WHERE  `weight` >= (SELECT `weight`
                    FROM   `TABLE`
                    WHERE  `id` = 7 
                    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY `id`
```

Comment: No, afaik. Only by joining the same table. But that won't be logical or advisable.

Comment: You forgot to order by weight :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to weight greater than id 7 record then this will work:

```
  SELECT id, 
         weight 
    FROM TABLE
   WHERE weight >= (SELECT weight 
                      FROM TABLE 
                     WHERE id = 7)
ORDER BY weight
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it with a `JOIN` rather than a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.weight
FROM TABLE AS t1
JOIN TABLE AS t2 ON t1.weight >= t2.weight
WHERE t2.id = 7
ORDER BY t1.weight
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with one select but you'll have to use user-defined variables
like this

```
SELECT id, weight,
       CASE WHEN id = 7 THEN @weight := weight
            ELSE @weight
       END AS compare_weight
FROM `TABLE`
HAVING weight >= compare_weight
ORDER BY weight ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a846/9